# How Can I input n-values to n-keys in a dictionary from user with python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```python
l=[]
n=int(input('enter number of list'))
[[] for i in range (n)]

for i in range (1, n+1):
    m=input('enter student')
    l.append(m)
    n=int(input('enter number of grades'))
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        y=int(input('enter grade'))
        l.append(y)
        s = ''.join(str(l)) 
print (*l,sep='')
```

and I would like to represent the input data as the following data:

[image]

Comment: add the sample input and expected output

Comment: Is is expected that all students have the same number of grades?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is the following:

```python
n=int(input('enter number of students'))
l=[]
for i in range (n):
    m=input('enter student name:')
    l.append([m])
    x=int(input(f'enter number of grades for {m}:'))
    for j in range (x):
        y=float(input(f'enter grade {j+1} for {m}:'))
        l[i].append(y) 
print(*l,sep=' ')
```

With the following input you'll get:

```python
enter number of students>? 2
enter student name:>? fdkfsd
enter number of grades for fdkfsd:>? 2
enter grade 1 for fdkfsd:>? 1.2
enter grade 2 for fdkfsd:>? 3.3
enter student name:>? sdsa
enter number of grades for sdsa:>? 3
enter grade 1 for sdsa:>? 34.5
enter grade 2 for sdsa:>? 43.2
enter grade 3 for sdsa:>? 12.2
['fdkfsd', 1.2, 3.3] ['sdsa', 34.5, 43.2, 12.2]
```

However, I would recommend using pandas.

Comment: Thank you buddy. You helped me so much! I owe you one!

Comment: @SergioSpitia could you please upvote the answer if it indeed help you